# Почему 'console' is not defined в grunt?

Tags: grunt, jshint

Узнал о таком замечательном инструменте как `gruntjs`. пытаюсь оттестировать его работу на простом `js` файле, но получаю ошибку от `jshint`:

```
src/main.js
  3 |   console.log("hello");
        ^ 'console' is not defined.
```

```js
(function () {
   'use strict';
   console.log("hello");
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="dist/all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Test Test
</body>
</html>
```

`Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: ['src/*.js'],
            dest: 'dist/all.js'
        }
    },
    jshint: {
        files: ['src/*.js'],
        options: {
            browser: true,
            bitwise: true,
            curly: true,
            eqnull: true,
            eqeqeq: true,
            // undef: true,
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        build: {
            src: 'dist/all.js',
            dest: 'dist/all.min.js'
        }
    },
    watch: {
        files: ['src/*.js', '*.html'],
        tasks: [ 'concat', 'jshint', 'uglify'],
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
```

};

Без параметра `undef: true` работает.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает без ошибок - Windows 7, Firefox.

Comment: @MarianD `>> 1 error in 1 file
Warning: Task "jshint:files" failed. Use --force to continue.`

Comment: @MarianD судя по всему надо добавить `globals`. Но не пойму как!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я не добавил `globals`:

```js
 jshint: {
   files: ['src/*.js'],
   options: {
   browser: true,
   bitwise: true,
   curly: true,
   eqnull: true,
   eqeqeq: true,
   globals: {
      undef: true
   }
  }
}
```

> Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task >> 1 file lint free.